# Async initialization in an ApiController

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, async-await, asp.net-web-api2

Does ApiController have an extension point/override that can be used to Initialize async resources?

I want to have something like this:

```
public ValuesController : ApiController
{
    private IFoo _foo;
    protected async override void InitializeAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext)
    {
        _foo = await CreateFooAsync();
    }
}
```

I know I can do this in each controller action but I would like to avoid having to do it in 4/5 different actions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can override core controller method: `ExecuteAsync`. Like this:

```
public override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) {
    _foo = await CreateFooAsync();
    return await base.ExecuteAsync(controllerContext, cancellationToken);
}
```